# Regular Expressions - Not Matching As Hoped

Tags: xml, string, matlab

Not able to get the correct matching I would like

I have a text similar to

```
<include randomText
    <include randomText
        <arg  name = nameOfInterest
    </include>
    <include randomText
        <arg  name = notInterestedInThis
    </include>
    <include randomText
        <arg  name = nameOfInterest
    </include>
</include>
```

I was trying the following and hoping for two matches, one for each include section that contains Name of Interest

```
[startIdxs,endIdxs] = regexp(string,'<(\w+).*>.*nameOfInterest.*</\1>')
```

What it does instead though is matches from the beginning of the first section that contains Name of Interest all the way to the end of the file at the very last include

This is a valid match, but not the one I was hoping for.

Is there a way to match only to the opening/closing includes that contain the argument Name of Interest, without hopping to the last include?

Hopefully that make sense

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Use non-greedy `.*?` to get the shortest match, not the longest match.

Comment: You also need `.*?>`

Comment: @bamar I have this, but still getting the same result
[startIdx,endIdx] = regexp(string,'<(\w+).*?>.*?nameOfInterest.*?</\1>')

Comment: You don't have any `>` before the first `nameOfInterest`.

Comment: @barmar I'm sorry I am not following you.  Could you provide an example of what you think I should do?

Comment: @barmar All good!  It clicked and now things are working.  Thank you!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/6rmDCP/1 for soemthing that comes close. But I suspect you don't want the first line in the first match. Making it not include both `<include` is tricky.

Comment: Yes, I was able to key off some extra text over here to eliminate that first line.  Your code is cleaner though, so I may try that out too.  Thanks again for the assistnace